# How can I scale more than 300% in Premiere?

Tags: premiere, effects, scale

I am using the transform effect to scale a clip. I need a scale of around 500%, however the scale control seems to be limited to 300%.

Is there any way I can scale the clip more than 300% using the transform effect?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using an older Version of Premiere:

As mentioned above, you can apply the maximum scale on the original clip,
then nest the clip (right click > Nest), and here apply another scale transformation.
With every iteration of this step you will gain 300%.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my version of the software (Premiere Pro CC 2018) it is possible to scale up to 10,000. I am not sure which of the latest software updates included this.

In earlier versions of the software, you can scale by the maximum amount, create a subclip and add another scale transformation.